# isUndoAvailable and isRedoAvailable undefined in handsontable

Tags: javascript, jquery, handsontable

This is first time I use the handsonTable. I am trying to have a menu button with items undo/redo outside the context menu of the handsontable, and to make those items enabled/disabled, I need to check if the undo and redo are available after the table is rendered. At my surprise, when I call the functions isUndoAvailable() and isUndoAvailable inside the afterRender handler (as stated in the documentation https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/wiki/Methods ), it causes the *undefined* JS error.

Here's a jsfiddle example of what I'm trying to do :

`var container = document.getElementById('example');
  var hot = new Handsontable(container,
  {
    data: data,
    minSpareRows: 1,
    colHeaders: true,
    contextMenu: true,
      afterRender: function(isForced){
          if(this.isUndoAvailable()){
             // do something
          }
      }
});`

Please have a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fkpLhco5/) example. Am I doing something wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nobody has an idea ? or a work around maybe. Please help :(

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have stumbled upon an edge case, in which the undo/redo plugin (seems) to load only after the `afterRender` callback.

```
hot.isUndoAvailable()
```

This works in other callbacks, at least a few I tried just now.
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/h5c6ks77/)'s an updated version of your fiddle, just call `isUndoAvailable` outside of the `afterRender` callback and it will work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But that doesn't solve my problem, as I want to constantly update the undo/redo buttons each time the table gets modified/altered. I thought the afterrender event was the more suitable one for that.

Comment: Actually the isUndo/RedoAvailable functions are not instantiated only during the first `afterRender` run, after that they are avaible (check in the fiddle, it logs `function()` on each new render, i.e. edits, etc).